# Stored procedure input parameters = "All"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What does it mean when you set an input parameter of a stored procedure to 'ALL'?

For example:

```sql
WHERE desk = @desk OR @desk = "ALL"
```

Is `All` a built-in SQL keyword? Like can you simply specify `All` in any stored procedure without having to adapt your table data, and it will simply return all records?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not a keyword. That is saying that if the user provided the word `'ALL'` as the parameter for `@desk`, then the column `desk` shouldn't be checked. In English, that query reads (reading backward):

> If the user provided the string "ALL", then they want to see all desks.
>
> Otherwise, check for the specific desk they asked for.

Performance is not great for one optional parameter, just wait until you get to 10 optional parameters. See some background:

- [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)
- [Answer: Sql where clause to return everything in case filter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63487310/61305)
- [Answer: indexing to support advanced search queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/280699/1186)

(In those cases you can consider `NULL` to be the equivalent of the word `'ALL'` - they both represent that the user doesn't want to filter on that column.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ALL` is a SQL keyword.  It can be used in contexts such as:

```
where x >= all (select y from t)
```

However, `"ALL"` is not a SQL keyword.  The only way it would be accepted by SQL Server in this context is if it were a column in a table.

I doubt that is the case.  I would guess that what you really intend is a *string*:

```
WHERE desk = @desk OR @desk = 'ALL'
```

Note that single quotes are quite different from double quotes.

In this context, it is just a string and a convention for whoever wrote this code to get everything.  It is standard in no way.  In fact, although there is not a standard, `NULL` is typically preferred:

```
WHERE desk = @desk OR @desk IS NULL
```

`NULL` has two advantages over `'ALL'`:

- It works for all data types.
- It cannot be confused with an actual value, because `=` doesn't work with `NULL` anyway.

Things get a bit trickier if you want to also test for `NULL` values, but that is not the question you asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Like Aaron said, "ALL" is not a keyword.

If you want to return ALL records if the keyword "ALL" is passed, you can do the following:

```sql
WHERE 
   1 = CASE 
          WHEN @desk="ALL" THEN 1
          WHEN desk=@desk THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END
```