# SQL Server add condition dynamically using case

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In my SQL Server stored procedure, I want to add a `Where` clause as dynamic as follows:

```
AND CASE WHEN @mySt <> '' THEN s.myStatus IN(@mySt) ELSE 0=0 END
```

When I want to check is: if `@mySt` is not empty, I want to add `s.myStatus IN(@mySt)`.

If if `@mySt` is empty, I want to skip this `where` clause.

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'IN'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql where clause to return everything in case filter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63486951/sql-where-clause-to-return-everything-in-case-filter-is-null)

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an **expression**, it returns a scalar value *not* a boolean result; you can't do want you're trying to do as `s.myStatus IN(@mySt)` isn't a scalar value.

Use proper boolean logic:

```sql
AND (s.myStatus = @mySt OR @mySt IS NULL) --I suggest NULL over a blank string
```

I replaced `IN` with `=`, as `@mySt` is a scalar value, so `IN` and `=` would be synonyms.

Comment: Adding one should consider the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint when using dynamic search conditions like this. TL;DR: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: `@mySt` will be a list like ('A','B','C') , using `=` will always return the wrong condition?

Comment: @StevenSann you can't set `@mySt` to have that value, it's a 3 values, and `@mySt` is clearly a scalar value. If you want to store multiple values, you should be using a table variable; and then you would use an `EXISTS` or `IN` with a subquery.

Comment: `@mySt` is storeprocedure parameter and it will come like "A,B,C"

Comment: You'll need to use a string splitter and a subquery then, @StevenSann . There are 1,000's of examples of these on [so]. But `Column IN (@variable)` is a synonym of `Column = @MyVariable'`. If the variable has delimited value, then it would just be `Column IN ('a,b,c')`, which is a synonym for `Column = 'A,B,C'`.